# Are there any script libraries that let me display MathML?

Tags: javascript, mathml

My website lets people paste html into a textbox, which gets displayed later to other users.  It occurred to me that they might want to display math formulas, and to do that in a browser, I would think the simplest method is MathML.

Is there a JavaScript library I can include in my pages that will make MathML render as formulas?
Thanks.

Comment: The first two results in google showed  [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) and its extension [ASCIIMath](http://asciimath.org/). Is there a reason you don't want to use them?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Mathjax looks good.  I didn't do the right search terms on Google.  I will incorporate it, and any competitors I find, in my website.